# Stub helper method for request spec in rails / rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mocking, helper, stub

I have a helper method called get_books_from_amazon that does an API call and returns an array of books.  I can't figure out how to stub it out in my request specs.

```
module BooksHelper
  def get_books_from_amazon(search_term)
    ...
  end
end

class StaticController < ApplicationController
  include BooksHelper
  def resources
    @books = get_books_from_amazon(search_term)
  end
end
```

I have tried the following in my spec, each to no avail:

```
# spec/requests/resource_pages_spec.rb
...
describe "Navigation" do
  it "should do such and such" do
    BooksHelper.stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array)
    StaticHelper.stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array)
    ApplicationHelper.stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array)
    StaticController.stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array[0..4])
    ApplicationController.stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array[0..4])
    request.stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array)
    helper.stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array)
    controller.stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array)
    self.stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array)
    stub!(:get_books_from_amazon).and_return(book_array)

    visit resources_path
    save_and_open_page
  end
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Helpers are typically used to clean up presentation "logic", so I wouldn't put something like a call to Amazon's API in a helper method.

Instead, move that method to a plain old Ruby class which you can call from your controller. 
An example might be:

```
class AmazonBookRetriever
  def get_books_from_amazon
    #code here
  end
end
```

Then your controller can call it:

```
def resources
  @books = AmazonBookRetriever.new.get_books_from_amazon(params[:search_term])
end
```

This should make mocking a lot easier.  You can stub `#new` on the `AmazonBookRetriever` to return a mock, and verify that it receives the `get_books_from_amazon` message.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I had considered making it a Books model, but this sounds a bit more accurate.  Where in the file tree do you normally put something like this?  Still in app/models?

Comment: Yes, you can -- and many people will say should-- put non-ActiveRecord models in app/models.

Answer (score 8):

Kendick's response is good advice in this situation.

I've added this in case anyone is actually looking for an answer to the original question:

```
ActionView::Base.any_instance.stub(:helper_method) { "substitute return value" }
```

Comment: For future searchers, check out `expect_any_instance_of` and `allow_any_instance_of` as well per rspec 3.0 [any_instance](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance#stubbing-any-instance-of-a-class-with-specific-arguments)